# Transformer derivation - reactance

Tags: transformer, coil, reactance

I'm struggling to understand a detail in the derivation of the transformer: N1/N2 = V1/V2.
The start of this derivation is to state that the input voltage Vi is equal to the voltage drop on the primary coil - that's clear. But then the next step depicts that the induced voltage is equal to the voltage drop on the coil to bring in the relation to faraday's law - that's weird for me as the induced voltage is the electrical reactance of the coil and therefore causes a voltage on the coil. How is it possible that the outer voltage on the primary coil is the same as the "inner" induced negative voltage?
Is my problem understandable?

Comment: Well it better be the same ,if it was not the current would be huge because DCR is very low

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 voltage.

As you probably know, Faraday's Law relates the flux in the core to the voltage across the coil such that:$$v_\phi=-N\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$.

When an input voltage \$V_{in}\$ is "applied" to the coil then the left-hand side of Faraday's equation is fixed to \$V_{in}\$,so that: $$v_{in}=-N\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$.

THere are no inner and outer voltages.